# C++ Closest Array Search

Tags: c++, arrays, function, search, random

OK so for my homework I have to make an array with 5 random values in it, ask the user for a number to search, then return the index of the number searched. All this is easy(or at least ive done it) but now if the number the user enters doesn't exist in the array then i have to still return the closest to it.

Example 1:

```
Int iArr[SIZE] = {45, 38, 198, 36, 781};

Int iSearchTarget = 199;
```

Returned Index = 2  (the index of 198)

---

Example 2:

```
Int iArr[SIZE] = {45, 38, 198, 36,781};

Int iSearchTarget = 37;
```

Returned Index = 1   (the index of 38)

... 
here is what my function looks like, i just need help on how you would find the "Closest" instead of returning -1.

```
int searchList(const int list[], int numElems, int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    int position = -1;
    bool found = false;

    while (index < numElems && !found)
    {
        if (list[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;
            cout << "The index of the number you searched for is "<<     position << endl;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (position == -1) {
        cout<<"Search not found" << position<<endl;
    }
    return position;
```

}

Comment: This is a question and answer site. That's not a question. Also, you may find someone who will just write the code for you, but that's not what this site is about either.

Comment: I already wrote the whole program I just need help with how you would find the closest number to that of one inside of the array. @JonathanWood

Comment: Think about how sorting the array might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be something like this...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int cSize = 5;
int iArr[cSize] = { 45, 38, 198, 36,781 };

int searchList(const int list[], int numElems, int value) {
    int diff = abs(list[0] - value) , idx{ 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
        if (abs(list[i] - value) < diff) {
            diff = abs(list[i] - value);
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return list[idx];
}

int main() {

    int num{ 0 };
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "The closest number is: " << searchList(iArr, cSize, num) << endl;

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANKS FOR NOT BEING A DICK LIKE @JonathanWood, with his shiitty ass website lol. Seriously thanks man, now i can go to sleep

Comment: i dont understand this line int diff{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max() }, idx{0};

Comment: It was to set the initial value to the highest possible integer value but there is no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach I would take.

I would start by storing the index of the first array item (0), along with the absolute difference between that item and `iSearchTarget`.

Next, I would loop through the rest of the array and for any item that has a smaller absolute difference to `iSearchTarget` than the one currently stored, I would replace the index and difference with that new item.

When you are done, you will have the index of the closest item.

But sorry, I'm not writing the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

After each iteration while searching take another variable (min) which stores the absolute difference of the numbers

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 if(arr[i]==iSearchTarget)
 { 
  //found 
 }
 else
 {
   p=abs(arr[i]-iSearchTarget) //absolute value of the difference
   if(p<min)
   {
    min=p;
    index=i;
   }
 }
}
// print the index or the difference according to your requirement
```

P.S. Its just an idea as how to proceed with the problem.Not the complete code

Comment: Your code has a bug. Did you test it?

Comment: It was just to give him the idea. Not the complete code

Comment: But you gave him the complete code, except with a bug.

Comment: Please would you point out the bug ?

Comment: I didn't test it, but I could see the bug you just fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

With algorithm, it becomes:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int searchNearest(const int (&a)[5], int value) {
    auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
                               [value](int lhs, int rhs) {
                                   return std::abs(lhs - value) < std::abs(rhs - value);
                               });
    return std::distance(std::begin(a), it);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 45, 38, 198, 36,781 };
    int num = 199;

    auto index = searchNearest(arr, num);
    std::cout << "The closest number is: " << arr[index]
              << " with index " << index << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f38e15c55d8b72d1)